# Buscar en un objeto mediante una string o un int

Tags: c++, string, object, template, class

Tengo una lista con platillas en base a un arreglo y lo que intento hacer es mediante una búsqueda lineal encontrar la posición de lo que ingreso ya sea un entero o una string pero siempre que lo intento el programa me dice que no puede convertir un entero o una string a mi objeto, o a la clase como tal. Tengo todos los operadores modificados. Por el momento me interesa compararlos mediante el nombre, se trata sobre canciones

Así es cómo intento obtener la posición de la string en el arreglo

```
    List<Song,5000> myLista;//Creación de la lista
    Song s;

    [...]
    }else if (op == "4"){
      string myStr;
      int pos;
      cout << "Ingresa el nombre de la cancion/artista a buscar: ";
      getline(cin, myStr);
      pos = myLista.linearFindData(myStr);
      cout << pos;//Test
    }
```

Este es el método en la clase con plantillas:

```
    template <class T, int ARRAYSIZE>
    int List<T, ARRAYSIZE>::linearFindData(const T& e) {
      int i(0);
      while( i<=last){
        if(data[i]==e){
          return i;
        }
     i++;
     }
   return -1;
   }
```

En la clase Song tengo esto:

```
    [...]
    Song::Song(){}
    Song::Song(const Song& s) : author(s.author), artist(s.artist), name(s.name), rank(s.rank){ }
    [...]
    string Song::toString(){
        char myRank[7];
        sprintf(myRank, "%d", rank);
        return author + "   |   " + artist + "   |   " + name + "   |   " + myRank;
    }

    Song& Song::operator=(const Song& s) {
        author = s.author;
        artist = s.artist;
        name = s.name;
        rank = s.rank;

        return *this;
    }

    ostream &operator << (ostream &o, Song &s){
       o << "Autor: " << s.getAuthor() << endl
         << "Artista: " << s.getArtist() << endl
         << "Nombre: " << s.getName() << endl
         << "Rango: " << s.getRank();

       return o;
    }

    istream& operator >> (istream& is, Song& s){
        getline(is, s.author);
        getline(is, s.artist);
        getline(is, s.name);
        cin>> s.rank;

        return is;
    }

    bool Song::operator==(const Song& s) {
        return name == s.name;
        }

    bool Song::operator!=(const Song& s) {
        return name != s.name;
        }

    bool Song::operator<=(const Song&s) {
        return name <= s.name;
        }

    bool Song::operator>=(const Song&s) {
        return name >= s.name;
        }

    bool Song::operator<(const Song&s) {
        return name < s.name;
        }

    bool Song::operator>(const Song&s) {
        return name > s.name;
        }
```

Este es el error que obtengo:
[image: :D]

Comment: Cómo hago para marcar la respuesta como solución?. EDIT. Ya vi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre solucionar el problema, a la hora de hacer la llamada al método de búsqueda. Utilizando el objeto creado:

```
    s.setName(myStr);//Uso el objeto
    pos = myLista.linearFindData(s);//Llamo al método con el objeto
    cout << pos;//Imprimo la posición en la que se encuentra
```

GRACIAS A QUIEN ME AYUDO A SOLUCIONARLO!!